# "QuerySet" prints before list result

Tags: python, django, shell, django-queryset

I'm building a blog in Django. I ran these commands in this order inside my virtualenv in the terminal:

```
python manage.py shell

from posts.models import Post

Post.objects.all()

Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=“example”)

Post.objects.create(title=“Djangohead”, content=“Born to raise shell, born to raise shell,
we know how to do it and we do it real well”)

Post.objects.all()

queryset = Post.objects.all()

for obj in queryset:
    print obj.title
    print obj.content
    print obj.updated
    print obj.timestamp
    print obj.id
    print obj.pk
```

I got correct results, including the first one `<[<Post: title example>]>`

Then I exited, ran the server, and did the same thing directly into `views.py` and `index.html`.

For practice, I deleted what I did in these two files and ran the commands again. Now, after typing

```
python manage.py shell

from posts.models import Post

Post.objects.all()
```

I'm getting "QuerySet" printed before the list:

```
<QuerySet [<Post: title example>]>
```

Why does it suddenly happen, and how do I reverse it back to the way it was? The only thing I did between the two is change my home folder name, but I hardly see how it could be related.

Comment: you have previously created a Post object and it has been saved into your db (probably sqlite)

Comment: @MehdiPourfar I'm not sure I understand. `title example` existed before I ran the first commands. `Djangohead`was created in the shell, then I deleted it in the Django Admin to go back to the way it was before running the commands.

Comment: That's the way it should work. It has been saved in your database before. You are doing weird things in your views and that's why new objects are created.

Comment: Django queries always return a queryset, that will still act exactly as you would expect; as an array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a misunderstanding of what you're doing and how you're doing it.

To directly answer your question of

> "Why does it suddenly happen"

```
>>> Post.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Post: title example>]>
```

is expected behavior when there is an item to return. Since you're not telling python to return the queryset to a variable, it returns it to stdout.

> and how do I reverse it back to the way it was?

What is happening isn't actually a problem. The language and the framework are behaving as expected.

Try something like this:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from posts.models import Post
>>> post = Post(title=“Djangohead”)
>>> post.save()
>>> other_post = Post(title=“FooBar”)
>>> other_post.save()
>>> posts = Post.objects.all()
>>> for post in posts:
...     print post.title

Djangohead
FooBar
```

I would highly recommend [The Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) which will go over all of this.

Comment: Thank you @Shonin. Finished the Django tutorials, and it does put a lot of the things I studied in perspective. I understand that QuerySet always prints with app.objects.all(). However, I still don't understand why it did not print the first time, then.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was wondering about that myself. In my experience sometimes these mysteries are best left unsolved. I'm glad I could help. Good luck on your journey with Django, it's a great framework.